# JavaScript and jQuery function calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

My html has jquery loaded:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Then, before ending body I load my custom file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="checkSum.js"></script>
</body>
```

My .js file looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //$('#sum').onclick(function(event){alert("onclick inside");}); //not norking

    //$( '#sum' ).on( 'click', function (event) { alert("on inside"); }); //working

    //function baubau(){alert("baubau inside")} //not working

});

//$('#sum').onclick(function(event){alert("onclick outside");}); //not norking

//$( '#sum' ).on( 'click', function (event) { alert("on outside"); }); //works

//function baubau(){alert("baubau outside")} //not working

$(document).on('click', '#sum', function() { alert("hello"); }); //works
```

After each line you can see the comment if the function gets called or not. Could anyone please help me understand the differences and also suggest me a good site to learn javascript and jQuery? I'm a Java developer but when it comes to javascript and jQuery, I've never ever understood anything :))

Comment: *"...and also suggest me a good site to learn javascript and jQuery?"* I'm afraid that part is off-topic for SO. But check out [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/).

Comment: You need to try understand of executions and method of jquery and javascript

Comment: And of course, the [jQuery site](http://jquery.com), which has links to tutorials. Or really just reading through [the API documentation](http://api.jquery.com) beginning to end only takes an hour or two, and is hugely useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With where you've put your script tag, there's no need to use `$(document).ready`. The only time you need to use that is when you don't control where your script tags go. If you do, and you put it at the end of the body as you've done, there's no need.

```
$('#sum').onclick(function(event){alert("onclick inside");}); //not norking
```

jQuery has no `onclick` method. Raw DOM elements do, but not jQuery instances (which are wrappers around sets of DOM elements [usually]).

```
$( '#sum' ).on( 'click', function (event) { alert("on inside"); }); //working
```

That's how you set up a direct click handler on an element with jQuery when looking it up by ID.

```
function baubau(){alert("baubau inside")} //not working
```

That declares a function, but doesn't call it. Unless something calls it, you won't see the `alert`.

```
$('#sum').onclick(function(event){alert("onclick outside");}); //not norking
```

See above.

```
$( '#sum' ).on( 'click', function (event) { alert("on outside"); }); //works
```

Because you don't need `ready` if you put your script at the end.

```
function baubau(){alert("baubau outside")} //not working
```

See above.

```
$(document).on('click', '#sum', function() { alert("hello"); }); //works
```

Hooks up a click handler on `document`, but only *fires* that handler if the event passes through an element matching the `'#sum'` selector you've provided. It's called *event delegation*. Very handy for setting up handlers for dynamically-added and -removed elements.

More in [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com).

Answer (score 1):

`onclick` is not a jQuery function, you had to use just `click`. And your function works too, you just have to call them too, not only declare them.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sum').click(function() {
        alert("click inside");
    });

    function baubau() {
        alert("baubau inside");
    }

    baubau();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has no .onclick method as far as I'm aware. Maybe you mean .click()?

```
$('#sum').onclick(function(event){alert("onclick inside");});
```

jQuery *does* have an .on method, and `click` in a valid event to hook into

```
$( '#sum' ).on( 'click', function (event) { alert("on inside"); });
```

functions do not run until they are *called*. So if you added `baubau()` within this document.ready function, it would get called, and the alert would happen.

```
function baubau(){alert("baubau inside")}
```